# ¿Se puede usar a la vez el encabezado fijo y responsive en una tabla?

Tags: bootstrap

Soy nuevo en Bootstrap, lo que pasa es que cuando cambio de tamaño el navegador quiero que me salga el scroll horizontal, pero no se puede, estoy hace dias tratando de encontrar una solución, les agradecería mucho si me ayudaran en esto. [Este es el codigo](https://www.codeply.com/go/MM4bfm8J7a)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías fijar el tamaño del div para todas las resoluciones, o al menos la mayoría de ellas, pero tendrías que dar mas información para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: aquí esta el codigo https://www.codeply.com/go/MM4bfm8J7a reduce de tamaño el navegador y te daras cuentas que el texto de tbody comienza a poner encima de otro, tambien quiero que sea la tabla responsive

Comment: dependiendo de lo que quieras podrias agregarle un 
`td{
    overflow-x: auto;
}` para que te permita hacer scroll horizontal a la celda de la tabla que se ve sobrepasada, no es elegante, pero es funcional, la otra es realmente plantearte si quieres que toda la tabla sea visible al ser responsive https://aukera.es/blog/tabla-html-responsive/ este articulo es interesante